# C++ range for loop different than regular for loop

Tags: c++

The range for loop is providing different addresses compared to the regular for loop. 
How can I use enhanced for loops?

`iArr` address: `011bf7cc`

Range for loop addresses: `011bf79c 011bf79c 011bf79c`

Regular for loop addresses: `011bf7cc 011bf79c 011bf7d4`

```
#include <iostream>
#include "TestingConstructors.h"
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;


int main() {
     int i, j, *i1, *i2;
     i = 1;
     j = 3;
     i1 = &i;
     i2 = &j;
     *i1 = 2;
     int iArr[3] = { 1,2,3 };
     cout << &iArr << endl << endl;
     for (int i : iArr)
          cout << &i << " ";
     cout << endl << endl;
     for (int i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE(iArr); i++)
          cout << &iArr[i] << " ";
     system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you put your code in italics?

Comment: The address of `i` does not change during the loop.

Comment: uhm mistake ill fix it

Comment: so how do i use enhanced for loops

Comment: There is no question.

Answer (score 8):

There is no such thing as an *"enhanced for loop"*. This is a "**range-for loop**":

```
for (int i : iArr)
      cout << &i << " ";
```

It gives you a different address because `int i : iArr` is **creating a copy of every element of `iArr`** and assigning it to `i`.

If you want to **refer** to the original elements, you should use

```
for (int& i : iArr)
      cout << &i << " ";
```